# Echo a custom field within a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field

So I have a custom field called 'ingredients'. I want to output this custom field information out onto my custom tab.

This is what I have but it echos out nothing.

```
function my_custom_tab(){

global $post;

echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ingredients', true);
}
```

Any ideas on why its not echoing anything out?

EDIT: Whatever I put in that last function I need to echo there like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98);

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ){

$tabs['my_custom_tab'] = array(
        'title' => "My Custom Tab",
        'priority' => 15,
        'callback' => 'my_custom_tab'

    );

return $tabs;
}
function my_custom_tab(){

echo '<h2>This is a title</h2>';
global $post;

return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ingredients', true);
}
```

If I insert that echo it will output that in the custom tab. Is there anyway to just say echo 'ingredients', the custom field?

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` then `echo` the function.

```
function my_custom_tab(){

    global $post;

    return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ingredients', true);
}

echo my_custom_tab();
```

`return` as you can guess, will pass the value back, so when you `echo` the function it should display the value.

Also make sure that `get_post_meta` is actually working.

Some background reading:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was alot simplier than I expected:

```
function my_custom_tab(){
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ingredients', true ); 
}
```